# Format a number as currency in a JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, number-formatting

Given a JTable where one of the columns contains a number, how do I display this number as a currency? I.e. 5 should display as $5.00 etc.

Can this be done directly on the JTable after it has been populated with data, or do I have to do this earlier?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to approach this. The up-front easiest might be to simply populate that column with a custom object that implements the currency formatting in its `toString()` method.

The other is to use a custom cell renderer. [Here](http://exampledepot.8waytrips.com/egs/javax.swing.table/CustRend.html) is some sample code for setting that up. It would have the advantage of being "done directly on the JTable after it has been populated with data."

Answer (score 1):

[Table Format Renderers](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/11/table-format-renderers/) shows how numbers and dates can easily be formatted.